# What is the generally expected or more useful form of supersymmetry, on-shell or off-shell?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, supersymmetry, action, ads-cft

If the on-shell numbers of degrees of freedom of bosons and fermions match we
have on-shell supersymmetry, if the off-shell numbers match we have off-shell
supersymmetry. When LHC people say they are searching for supersymmetry are they searching for the on-shell or off-shell or both?

In the *Introduction to the ADS/CFT Correspondence* by Horatiu Nastase it was mentioned that for the Super Yang-Mills theory only the on-shell version is known and there is no fully off-shell formulation with Lorentz invariance. Does that mean the results (*not talking about the results which are useful in QCD calculations irrespective of whether supersymmetry is real, talking about Quantum Gravity results related to the Black Hole Information Paradox etc*) of ADS/CFT are valid only if the universe has on-shell version of supersymmetry and are invalid if the universe has the off-shell version?

Or is it like we can always (in principle) introduce some auxiliary fields so that we have both on-shell and off-shell supersymmetry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On-shell SUSY means the theory is supersymmetric when taking into account equations of motion. Off-shell means that the action is supersymmetric even before writing equations of motion (obviously off-shell SUSY holds on shell as well). Physically, we are interested in on-shell stuff, because physics is ultimately expressed by equations of motion, but off-shell SUSY is still useful because it helps us to write down most general interactions between various supermultiplets.

Comment: Since off-shell SUSY holds on-shell as well, the results of ADS/CFT are valid even if SUSY is off-shell right?

Comment: @KasiReddySreemanReddy yes, if off-shell SUSY is available (it is not always available)